# Why can't I use '+' to merge dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, concatenation, addition

I am a new Python user and I would have some doubts.

I know I that the `+` operator not only performs sum between numbers but also concatenation between strings or lists. Why this is not allowed for dictionaries?

Comment: It *could* be defined maybe, even if it's not obvious what this definition would be, but the actual answer is "because the designers of the Python language decided to not define the + operator for dictionaries".

Comment: You will find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python/26853961#26853961

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an accepted PEP for this, coming in Python 3.9 :)

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/#specification

> d = {'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'cheese': 3}
>
> e = {'cheese': 'cheddar', 'aardvark': 'Ethel'}
>
> d | e
>   {'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'cheese': 'cheddar', 'aardvark': 'Ethel'}
>
> e | d
>   {'aardvark': 'Ethel', 'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'cheese': 3}

Answer (score 3):

How would the `+` operator for dicts handle duplicate keys? e.g.

```
>>> {'d': 2} + {'d': 1}
```

Perhaps like a `Counter`?

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter({'d': 2}) + Counter({'d': 1})
Counter({'d': 3})
```

Or like a `defaultdict`?

```
{'d': [2, 1]}
```

Or overwriting the 1st key like `dict.update`?

```
>>> d = {'d': 2}
>>> d.update({'d':1})
>>> d
{'d': 1}
```

Or leaving only the 1st key?

```
{'d': 2}
```

It's frankly ambiguous!

See also [PEP 0584](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/#use-the-addition-operator):

> **Use The Addition Operator**
>
> This PEP originally started life as a
>   proposal for dict addition, using the + and += operator. That choice
>   proved to be exceedingly controversial, with many people having
>   serious objections to the choice of operator. For details, see
>   previous versions of the PEP and the mailing list discussions.

Note Guido himself did [consider and discuss this](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-ideas@python.org/thread/BHIJX6MHGMMD3S6D7GVTPZQL4N5V7T42/); see also [issue36144](https://bugs.python.org/issue36144).

Comment: Adding to this: the nearest equivalent would be `dict.update`, but note that the name is explicitly *update*, suggesting that values will be replaced, which `+` doesn't suggest…